# Running django test on the gitlab ci

Tags: python, django-testing, django-1.4, gitlab-ci

I have project in django 1.4 and I need to run django test in contious integration system (GitLab 6.8.1 with Gitlab CI 4.3).

Gitlab Runner have installed on server with project.

When I run:

> cd project/app/ && ./runtest.sh test some_app

I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management`

How I may run tests?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Django installed on the testrunner?

If not, try to configure a virtualenv for your testsuite. Best might be (if you have changing requirements) to make the setup and installation of this virtualenv part of your testsuite.

Answer (score 0):

Change your job script in gitlab-ci with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:10
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py test
```

Before doing this,. install virtualenv and xvfb (for selenium test) for GitLab runners.